# Forking three subprocesses gives weird random output

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I try to make three processes to pipe to each other. However I am really puzzled with forking the third process. Forking and piping **only two** processes works without problem. When I add +1 loop to test if the third process spawns, I get weird results in terminal.

This is my code(with the weird results):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

  int status, i;
  int pip[2];


  /* Spawn 3 subprocesses and pipe the first 2*/
  for (i=0; i<3; i++){

    if (i==0) pipe(pip);

    if (fork()==0){

      /* First subprocess */
      if (i==0){
        dup2(pip[1], 1); //pip[0] will replace stdout
        close(pip[0]);
        if (execlp("ls", "ls", NULL)) perror("process1");
      }

      /* Second subprocess */
      if (i==1){
        dup2(pip[0], 0); //pip[1] -> will replace stdin
        close(pip[1]);
        if (execlp("more", "more", NULL)) perror("process2");
      }

      /* Third subprocess */
      if (i==2){
        close(pip[0]); //reseting fd
        close(pip[1]); //reseting fd
        open(0);       //reseting fd
        open(1);       //reseting fd
        if (execlp("ls", "ls", NULL)) perror("process3");
      }


    }
  }

    wait(&status);
    return 0;
}
```

Changing the the for-loop to 2 loops instead of 3 stops the weird behaviour.
The weird behaviour is that randomly I will get one of these outputs in terminal:

```
manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ ./test
test  test2.c  test3.c  test4.c  test.5c  test.c
test
test2.c
test3.c
test4.c
test.5c
test.c
manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$
```

In that case it worked as normally. Now at some points it goes like this:

```
manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ test
test2.c
test3.c
test4.c
test.5c
test.c
test  test2.c  test3.c  test4.c  test.5c  test.c
manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$
```

Where hitting enter just writes the prompt and waits for more input. The third  weird behaviour is this:

```
manos@megistanas:~/Desktop/test$ test
test2.c
test3.c
test4.c
test.5c
test.c
(blinking prompt symbol)
```

Once I hit enter the program ends normally. Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

> open(0);
>
> open(1);

Please read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) for open(2).

Hint: it doesn't take one parameter. You should probably build with `-Wall`, and pay attention to compiler warnings.

This probably doesn't completely explain what you are seeing, but given this obvious bug, I am too lazy to look any further.

Comment: Forgot that -Wall. Will see if I get something from that.